# FadeIn and FadeOut jumps page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, page-jump

I have the following code:

```js
if (vm.theNextStep === true) {
    vm.theNextStep = false;
    vm.setSuccess = true;
    $('#theNextStep').fadeOut(500);
    $('#setSuccess').fadeIn(1500);
    $('#setSuccess').fadeOut(2000);
}
```

```css
#setSuccess {
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    background: #7CB130 url(check_white.png') no-repeat center;
    min-height: 85px;
    padding-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="setSuccess" ng-show="vm.paymentSuccess"></div>
```

***The page jumps upon page fadeIn***. How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The page jumps because you have two lines of code runs one after another, that doesn't wait for one to finish it.

You can put the `fadeIn` code in the callback of the first `fadeOut`:

```
if (vm.theNextStep === true) {
    vm.theNextStep = false;
    vm.setSuccess = true;
    $('#theNextStep').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $('#setSuccess').fadeIn(1500).fadeOut(2000);
    });

}
```

Comment: In addition, if what you want to do a "crossfade" effect, use `position: absolute` for each step container.

Comment: @TrinhHoangAnh Absolutely! That can be done wrapping all the elements in a relatively positioned element and that will just work fine.